# BigQuery query history: get performance counters/metrics

Tags: google-bigquery, query-performance, metrics, performancecounter

What are the best practices to get the historical query metrics. Let's assume there were 3 users, they did run 3, 4, 5 queries respectively during a day (through JDBC/ODBC). How could I get a list of those queries along with other metadata information, eg. price, data volume scanned, slots, start/end time, rows returned etc…

Could I also get the *explain/execution plan* equivalent for those queries?

I saw somewhere I could try to use the CLI:

- Listing all query jobs: `bq ls -j -q`
- Getting the data for specific job: `bq show --format=prettyjson -j <Job ID>`

or maybe API could give me more information?

but ultimately what is the best/recommended practice here?

For instance in AWS RedShift I can use views/meta tables like `STL_QUERY`, `STL_QUERYTEXT`, `STL_CONNECTION_LOG`, `SVL_QUERY_SUMMARY` view etc… I am wondering if there's similar mechanism to use SQL to access **and filter** that information?

Answer (score 2):

> ... or maybe API could give me more information?

You can use [Jobs: list](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/list) and [Jobs: get](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/get) to respectively lists jobs started in the specified project and return information about a specific job.

If Jobs.get call is successful, this method returns a [Jobs resource](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#resource) in the response body where you can find all details you mentioned in your question

Answer (score 1):

You can use BigQuery webUI to fetch all information, remember there is a limit 1000 records BUT it gives you a nice an elegant way similar to AWS option.

This is how you set the option to see ALL your users jobs:

[image]

And using the search box you can apply filters on your search

[image]

Clicking on the arrow on the right side gives some advanced options:

[image]

Comment: but can I use BQ SQL query to get same? exactly like in AWS?

Comment: I would describe it as "filtering" on top of your query history which is nice but not as clean as AWS solution. Nevertheless, it does provide search functionality that the API/CLI doesn't. On a side note, If it helps superQuery [Web IDE](https://superquery.io) does close the gap on this feature and provides full SQL querying on top of the organization query history as AWS does.